# Cannot Convert Type Void to Generic List

Tags: c#, generics

I have two lists: a list of countries and a list of jobs

```
public List<Countries> getSharedCountries(string brandName)
    {
        var items = SharedJobs.Where(a => a.BrandName == brandName);

        var items2 = items.OrderBy(a => a.CountryCode);

        Countries = new List<Countries>();

        string Country = null;

        foreach (var item in items2)
        {
            if (Country != item.CountryCode)
            {
                Country = item.CountryCode;

                Countries.Add(new Countries() { CountryCode = item.CountryCode, JobIDs = getSharedJob(item.CountryCode) });
            }
        }
        return Countries;
    }

    public void getSharedJob(string Country)
    {
        var items = SharedJobs.Where(a => a.CountryCode == Country);

        JobNetDetails = new List<JobDetail>();
        CareerBoardDetails = new List<JobDetail>();
        JobSharkDetails = new List<JobDetail>();
        JobServeDetails = new List<JobDetail>();

        int AusCount = 0;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (Country == "AUS")
            {
                AusCount++;

                if (AusCount % 4 == 0)
                {
                    JobNetDetails.Add(new JobDetail() { JobPageTitle = item.JobPageTitle, JobID = item.JobID, JobUrl = item.JobUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    JobServeDetails.Add(new JobDetail() { JobPageTitle = item.JobPageTitle, JobID = item.JobID, JobUrl = item.JobUrl });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

On the line where I am accessing the method getSharedJob, it errors and gives me the error, cannot implicitly convert void to system.generic.List?

I am very confused as to why this is happening?

Comment: this is happening because you are not returning anything from the method th return type is void

Comment: I need to return 4 lists, from the bottom method, how would you go about doing this?

Comment: You can only return one object. So create a class with 4 lists, or you could add 4 list parameters to the method (and tag them with `out`

Answer (score 1):

As the signature of your method states, `public void getSharedJob(string Country)` it's void, so it doesn't return anything, you should change it and return the list you wish.

Edit: As I read in the comments you need to return 4 Lists.
You have several options:

- You can return an array of Lists;
- You can return a List of Lists;
- You can return your own class containing the 4 Lists.

Comment: How would you go about returning a a class of the 4 lists?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code which returns jobDetails from the method you are calling

```
 public List<Countries> getSharedCountries(string brandName)
            {
                var items = SharedJobs.Where(a => a.BrandName == brandName);

                var items2 = items.OrderBy(a => a.CountryCode);

                Countries = new List<Countries>();

                string Country = null;

                foreach (var item in items2)
                {
                    if (Country != item.CountryCode)
                    {
                        Country = item.CountryCode;
                        foreach (var jobDetail in getSharedJob(item.CountryCode))
                        {
                           Countries.Add(new Countries() { CountryCode = item.CountryCode, JobIDs = jobDetail.JobID });
                         }
                    }

                }
                return Countries;
            }

            public List<JobDetail> getSharedJob(string Country)
            {
                var items = SharedJobs.Where(a => a.CountryCode == Country);

                JobNetDetails = new List<JobDetail>();
                CareerBoardDetails = new List<JobDetail>();
                JobSharkDetails = new List<JobDetail>();
                JobServeDetails = new List<JobDetail>();

                int AusCount = 0;

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    if (Country == "AUS")
                    {
                        AusCount++;

                        if (AusCount % 4 == 0)
                        {
                            JobNetDetails.Add(new JobDetail() { JobPageTitle = item.JobPageTitle, JobID = item.JobID, JobUrl = item.JobUrl });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            JobServeDetails.Add(new JobDetail() { JobPageTitle = item.JobPageTitle, JobID = item.JobID, JobUrl = item.JobUrl });
                        }
                    }
                }

              return JobServeDetails;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature says take a string variable and return nothing (void).

```
public void getSharedJob(string country)
```

JobIDs is expecting a value

```
JobIDs = getSharedJob(item.CountryCode)
```

so you need to return a value which matches the JobIDs type which I assume is a List of ints or a List of JobDetails.